# SQL Server Output Clause equivalent in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase15

Is there a SQL Server Output clause equivalent in Sybase Version 15? As far as I know there's no Output clause in Sybase which gives the output rows from Update, delete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is no directly identical statement-level clause. However you can achieve the same effect with a trigger.